# Visual Studio Code Can't Run Flutter - looking at wrong dart version

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, flutter-android

I have created a new flutter Project, but when I run it on Visual Studio Code by clicking on "Start Debugging" the following errors pops up:

```
[button_test] flutter pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in button_test...                     
The current Dart SDK version is 2.17.6.

Because button_test requires SDK version >=2.18.4 <3.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; Because button_test requires SDK version >=2.18.4 <3.0.0, version solving failed.)
exit code 1
```

So I've double checked the dart version by entering `dart --version`. But this came back as **2.18.6**

The funny thing is that if I enter `flutter run` on the Terminal, it works no problem. As I've installed the flutter and dart extension, I believe this is a problem with those extension? With that said, is there a way to fix which version of dart it's looking at?

Thanks

Comment: You probably have two versions of dart installed on your computer. Flutter comes bundled with its own version of dart so that you do not need to install dart independently.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:
Open terminal and Navigate to the flutter location

cd <flutter_path>

Step 2:
Now enter the command

git checkout

You can find all the releases from this link https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/releases

Step 3:
Now run flutter doctor -v command so flutter will download the stuff related to the particular version

flutter doctor -v

Once the flutter doctor command is successful you can go ahead and enjoy the version you wish